# Anti spam temporary e-mail service

Tags: webapp-rec, email, spam-prevention

Please list some web apps that allows you either to

- create temporarily forwarding addresses (like [mailexspire](http://www.mailexpire.com/))
- use anonymous inboxes (like [mailinator](http://mailinator.com/))

As always with such lists: one service per answer.

Comment: I like [SpamBox](http://spambox.us/) - dead simple to use.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use [plus-addressing in Gmail](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/980/use-gmail-plus-addressing-to-generate-throw-away-e-mail-addresses/). Basically you just pop a + after the username part of your email (alex+foo@example.com will go to the mailbox for alex@example.com, but will allow easy filtering). They're sort of temporary and not really anonymous, but they would allow you to filter out based on rules etc. Big downside is that clever spammers would just remove the + to get around your cunning filters.

Comment: Plus addresses are being accepted less and less - I find using Google Apps + your own domain and this "minus addressing" workaround works nicely:

http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108/alternatives-to-plus-addressing/1000#1000

Comment: @3rdparty - yeah, that looks pretty cool :)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a [Google Apps](http://apps.google.com/) account with your own domain name (so you can have unlimited email addresses). Just add a temporary alias for your normal user - allow the email you want to come in, then remove the alias... A lot more temporary than my other answer and a bit more anonymous. Still not perfect...

Comment: The free apps account only allows for 50 accounts, but each account can have aliases - not sure if there's a limit to the number of aliases per account or not.

Comment: I've got quite a few aliases set up (not 50 though) and there's no mention of a limit...

Comment: you can setup as well a "catch-all" address / account. then just let the mail come.

Answer (score 1):

[OtherInbox](http://otherinbox.com)'s DEFENDER offering has this functionality.  You sign up and get  USERNAME.otherinbox.com and USERNAME.oib.com subdomains (or you can use your own domain) and it sorts/filters anything sent to that domain.

I've been using the service for over 2 years now and have been pretty happy with it.  They started off focusing on providing a web mail client experience but have since started focusing more on tapping into existing webmail accounts (gmail, yahoo) and sorting messages that come in based on type.

Make sure to sign up using the DEFENDER link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Sxipper](http://www.sxipper.com/) plug-in for Firefox, and it includes a temporary e-mail redirection service.

Answer (score 0):

[10MinuteMail](http://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Temp Alias](http://tempalias.com/). It allows you to set how many days the email will be active for, but another unique feature is you can set how many email's it is alive for. So for example you could say after this email has been emailed 3 times, destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was mentioned in the question, but I like [Mailinator](http://mailinator.com/) ([alt](http://www.spamherelots.com)) the best of any service I've tried.  Primarily because of its [alternate names](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2008/03/introducing-alternate-inbox-names.html) feature.  I used one of those to set my Meta SO gravatar to be different than my SO/SF/SU avatar.

Answer (score 0):

[temporaryinbox.com](http://www.temporaryinbox.com), which also has a [Firefox extension](http://www.freewarefiles.com/Temporary-Inbox-Firefox-Extension_program_21634.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Yopmail](http://www.yopmail.com/en/)

For a temporary address for receiving e-mail, you can use Yopmail. Just don't forget to delete your message after you have read them since everyone can read the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I use dispostable. It's not secure, meaning anyone who goes to whatever@dispostalbe can see Whatever's email. No passwords at all. But you can delete messages after you use the mail verification link.

It's not temporary. I check it every day as I have my more spammy advert emails going there.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetable](http://www.jetable.org/en/index) will forward to the address you specify for one hour/day/week/month.

Answer (score 0):

[myTrashMail.com](http://www.mytrashmail.com/)

Key features:

- use any email name you want
- no sign up or password to remember
- forward/delete emails
- hypertext enabled
- email stays to between 5 to 30 days in your account
- every account can hold up to 4MB
- email size is limited to 2MB per email