# Random domain (and not just username) temporary email service

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I need a temporary email to register on one web service and not to receive spam later. But the thing is that they block emails from all known temporary and public email services. Is there a temporary email provider which registers a random domain, provides an email for temporary use and then cancels the domain? So I need an email like user@*random*.com, and not the one like *random*@constant.com. And 10minutemail.com is not suitable since its domains are known to the web service.

Comment: How much would you be prepared to pay? The cost of registering the domain would probably exceed that. You can't just register a domain for 10 minutes.

Comment: The thing is - it is possible to register the domain and then cancel it.

Comment: A common price of a .com name is $8-$15 per year paid up-front. You can't register a domain for an hour without paying the yearly fee.

Comment: Actually, some scammers use the practice of "domain tasting" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_tasting )to register domains for up to 5 days without paying for them.

There's probably not a lot of overlap between people who set up these 5-day domains and people who want to help you avoid spam. Actually, I suspect those people are the same people who want to spam you. So I don't think they're going to be offering free disposable webmail any time soon.

Comment: Have you checked all the providers from this question http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/anti-spam-temporary-e-mail-service/?

Answer (score 2):

[Mailinator](http://www.mailinator.com) will accept mail for any domain - so if you have a domain of your own, or if you want to register one yourself, you can point the MX records for a host/domain name to mailinator, and then pick up the email thru Mailinator's web interface.

Answer (score 2):

The best idea maybe would be just to register an own domain and set up an E-Mail server (or just use Google Apps) with an catch-all address. It is very unlikely that your domain will get on the service's blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to register your own domain for use with Mailinator you can use a free service like [no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html).

You will need an email address to sign up though ;-)